# Word to describe when a person is interrupted by a trivial correction, distracting from the point?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, terminology

Is there a word for a "technically accurate correction, but one that nobody needed.  Something that causes a digression, which may or may not have been an attempt to diminish the original point by making it seemed flawed"?

I think there should be.

Red Herring doesn't seem to fit, because the context isn't a debate. A specialist of any type (Grammar, English, engineering, science, history, etc) are prone to making this mistake in mixed company.

Comment: Are you asking about the person or the thing that annoys the person?

Comment: **Easily distracted person**?

Comment: **Pedantic, Overscrupulous**

Comment: In most real-world contexts where I might need to refer to the distraction, I'd just say it's ***[an irrelevant] technical detail***.

Comment: The substance of the distraction is ***neither here nor there***.

Comment: http://geekfeminism.wikia.com/wiki/Derailment perhaps?

Comment: Why do you characterize it as a mistake? Why do you think nobody needed it - obviously someone did? And yes, I'm doing this on purpose;-)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a ***nit***:

> :  a minor shortcoming
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nit)</sub>

This is more often used in this sense in the word *nitpick*.

Answer (score 3):

How about a **"Pedant" (n.)**

> a person who annoys other people by correcting small errors and giving too much attention to minor details
>
> - Merriam Webster
>
> "All too often, science fiction provokes the pedant in professional scientists, for whom a beautiful story can be ruined by a single petty error." —Jerry A. Coyne, New York Times Book Review, 10 Oct. 1999

Or "Pedantic" (Adj.) would probably work better for your usage.

Answer (score 1):

**Having gone on a tangent** seems right, which is discussion of a mostly irrelevant part of the overall point.

Comment: I'd suggest "tangential" to meet the single-word requirement. :)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the offending person's motivations:

1. If the person is concerned about *absolute* correctness ([A "Type C personality"](https://www.discprofile.com/what-is-disc/overview/conscientiousness/)), then he is being **Pedantic**.
   [From Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pedantic):

   > 1. Like a pedant, overly concerned with formal rules and trivial points of learning.
   > 2. Being showy of one’s knowledge, often in a boring manner.
   > 3. Being finicky or fastidious, especially with language.
2. If the person is hostile to the victim and wants to disrupt or negate him (As happens constantly in politics and in "news" interviews), then he can be said to **Abash** the victim.
   [From Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abash):

   > To make ashamed; to embarrass; to destroy the self-possession of, as by exciting suddenly a consciousness of guilt, mistake, or inferiority; to disconcert; to discomfit.
3. Particularly vicious or sustained (a)bashing becomes [**Heckling**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heckle).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps rephrasing in order to highlight my word of choice:

```
     MINUTIAE: the small, precise, or trivial details of something
```

These sporadic queries about minutiae which you persistently interject
only serve to derail my delivery of all the pertinent facts and 
render me incapable of completing my report on the events of last
night.